# Value of an expression involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose $a$ is a complex number such that $$a^2+a+\frac 1a +\frac 1{a^2} +1 =0$$ If $m$ is a positive integer find value of $$a^{2m}+a^m+\frac 1{a^m} +  \frac 1{a^{2m}}$$

Setting $a=|a|e^{i\theta}$ we get $$2|a| \cos \theta  + 2 |a|^2 \cos 2\theta+1=0$$ I could not get anything from this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Show that $a^5=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that avoids (explicit) trigonometry:

**Hint** Multiplying the equation through by $a^2$ gives
$$a^4 + a^3 + a^2 + a + 1 = 0 ,$$
which we can rewrite as
$$\frac{a^5 - 1}{a - 1} = 0.$$

Comment: Another version of this is to multiply both sides of the original equation by $a-1$ and note that it simplifies to $a^3-a^{-2}=0$.

Comment: @Travis Perhaps a silly question but what is the reasoning that allows the quartic function to simplify to that fraction? I've tried looking it up but I'm having no luck.

Comment: This is usual formula for the sum of a geometric sequence. To see how it works in this case, multiply $a^4 + \cdots + a + 1$ by $a - 1$ and see what happens.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. Now I understand. :)